# CakePHP how to log API requests globally?

Tags: cakephp, logging, global

I have an API based on CakePHP, controller with name AccessLogController is responsible for saving access log into the database.

**Question is:**

What is the best practice for global logging in CakePHP?

I thought that I will call AccessLogController method from inherited AppController in before filter callback like this:

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
        $accessLogCtrl = new AccessLogsController();
        $accessLogCtrl->add($param1, $param2);
    }
```

But i not sure that is it a good way how to do it..

Many Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you should use controllers, never ever, except maybe in your test suite!

That being said, using `AppController::beforeFilter()` to globally log controller action requests is generally fine, just make sure that you always invoke `parent::beforeFilter()` in case you are overriding the filter in an extending controller.

However, you should definitely refactor your logging functionality into either a utility class, a component, a model, or even directly into `AppController`, depending on how it's actually logging things, and if you need to use it in places other than in `AppController`.

Comment: Could You please provide some example code, how to it in Each request to the API?

Comment: @redrom I don't know anything about your apps internals, so how do you expect me to write any code, other than what you are already showing here, ie a `beforeFilter()` callback?